# Are there "official" Javadocs available for MySQL JDBC Connector?

Tags: documentation, javadoc, mysql-connector

Are there javadocs available for MySQL JDBC connector? If so, where can I find them?

Googling around, I've come across links such as [Class MysqlDataSource](http://www.control.auc.dk/~04gr733/filer/javadoc-DB-driver/com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource.html) . But it is that official? I guess I'm looking for something that came from mysql.com or affiliates. Is there such thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [official documentation of Connector/J is here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/). It does not, as far as I know, contain any JavaDoc. The reason for this is that you should not need to directly refer to any of those classes. You should be able to use only the `java.sql.*` classes to access the DB.

Comment: I came here looking for information on the javadocs, too. The reason is that the connector has two different CommunicationsException classes and I wanted to see if one inherited from the other (they don't) and under which circumstances one would be thrown instead of the other.

Comment: There is more to a JDBC driver than merely a direct implementation of the JDBC API. One major example would be the driver’s implementation(s) of the [`javax.sql.DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface which will include a variety of getters/setters for database-specific properties. In the case of Connector/J for MySQL 8, it would be quite helpful to see Javadoc for the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` class, as discussed on [this Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/270786/19079).

Answer (score 4):

Joachim is correct.
However, there are some issues left for vendor-specific implementation (for example, does `Connection.close()` while a transaction is open commits or rollback).

In such cases you can check out the [MySQL JDBC API Implementation Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) or look at the Java docs and source in the [MySQL source code](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/mysql-connector-java)